# Is there a way to convert table data to an Excel-like interface?

Tags: jquery, excel, graph, html-table

I'm looking for a way to create graphs, or sort by fields, so turn my `<table>` into aN Excel-like interface. Is there a jQuery way, or plugin for this?

Say I have a table like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>points</td>
        <td>timestamp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ashley</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>03-10-2013-etc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Ashley</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>04-10-2013-etc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Bill</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>03-10-2013-etc</td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Can I do something that converts this table to meaningful visualized data?
something like this :

```
<script>
$("table").sortBy("points");
$("table").graph("timestamp" , "points");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few free open source options such as:

- [JQ Plot](http://www.jqplot.com/)
- [Charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)
- [Google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)